# Jquery slider - cant fill all squares in the slider

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

My problem is that i dont know how to connect the posts in the data base (the articles) with the slider. I mean i did it with the 1st one but i dont know how to do it with the others.

Here is the code of the content php file where is the slider:
I hope someone can tell me how to fill the other 4 slidr squares.

```
<div id="main_content">


<?php
include("includes/connect.php");

$select_posts= "select * from posts order by rand() LIMIT 0,1";

$run_posts = mysql_query($select_posts);

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($run_posts)) {

$post_id = $row['post_id'];
$post_title = $row['post_title'];
$post_date = $row['post_date'];
$post_author = $row['post_author'];
$post_image = $row['post_image'];
$post_content = substr($row['post_content'],0,50);



?>


<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="content">
      <div id="featured_slide">
        <ul id="featurednews">
          <li><center><img src="images/<?php echo $post_image; ?>" width="500" height="300"  /></center>
            <div class="panel-overlay">
              <h2><?php echo $post_title; ?></h2>
              <p align="justify"><?php echo $post_content; ?></p><br/>
              <a href="pages.php">Continue Reading &raquo;</a>
              </li>
          <li><img src="images1/demo/2.gif" alt="" />
            <div class="panel-overlay">
              <h2><?php echo $post_title; ?></h2>
              <p>Temperinte interdum sempus odio urna eget curabitur semper convallis nunc laoreet.<br />
                <a href="#">Continue Reading &raquo;</a></p>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li><img src="images1/demo/3.gif" alt="" />
            <div class="panel-overlay">
              <h2>Dapiensociis temper donec</h2>
              <p>Temperinte interdum sempus odio urna eget curabitur semper convallis nunc laoreet.<br />
                <a href="#">Continue Reading &raquo;</a></p>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li><img src="images1/demo/4.gif" alt="" />
            <div class="panel-overlay">
              <h2>Semvelit nonummy odio tempus</h2>
              <p>Justolacus eger at pede felit in dictum sempus elit curabitur ipsum. Ametpellentum.<br />
                <a href="#">Continue Reading &raquo;</a></p>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li><img src="images1/demo/5.gif" alt="" />
            <div class="panel-overlay">
              <h2>Pedefamet orci orci quisque</h2>
              <p>Nonnam aenenasce morbi liberos malesuada risus id donec volutpat estibulum curabitae.<br />
                <a href="#">Continue Reading &raquo;</a></p>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <?php } ?>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For one thing you didn't close the 'panel-overlay' div for the first slide or the div with id 'featured_slide', which is probably why the other slides aren't displaying.

Also, from what I understand of what you are trying to do, once you fix the errors mentioned above, it looks like all you need to rearrange your code to look more like this:

```
<div id="main_content">
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="content">
      <div id="featured_slide">
        <ul id="featurednews">

<?php
include("includes/connect.php");

$select_posts= "select * from posts order by rand() LIMIT 0,1";

$run_posts = mysql_query($select_posts);

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($run_posts)) {

$post_id = $row['post_id'];
$post_title = $row['post_title'];
$post_date = $row['post_date'];
$post_author = $row['post_author'];
$post_image = $row['post_image'];
$post_content = substr($row['post_content'],0,50);
?>
          <li><center><img src="images/<?php echo $post_image; ?>" width="500" height="300"  /></center>
            <div class="panel-overlay">
              <h2><?php echo $post_title; ?></h2>
              <p align="justify"><?php echo $post_content; ?></p><br/>
              <a href="pages.php">Continue Reading &raquo;</a>
              </div>
              </li>   
    <?php } ?>
     </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```